# Shifting my navbar after adding a line to my html table

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

I'm having a problem with my javascript code. I've written a method that lets me add a row to an html table, but only every time I add a row my form shifts upwards.

here is my code

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import { getDeviseRateAjax, calcAgainstValue } from "../helper";
import $ from 'jquery'
import Routing from "fos-router";
import routes from "../js/routes.json";

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = ["collectionContainer", "elementRow"];
    static values = {
        index: Number,
        prototype: String,
        operationtype: Number,
    }

    connect() {
        super.connect();
        Routing.setRoutingData(routes);
    }

    addCollectionElement(event){
        const item = document.createElement('tr');
        item.setAttribute("data-form-collection-target", 'elementRow')
        item.innerHTML = this.prototypeValue.replace(/__name__/g, this.indexValue);
        $(this.collectionContainerTarget).append(item);
        this.indexValue++;

        const selectDevise = item.children[0].lastElementChild;
        const inputDevise = item.children[1].lastElementChild;
        const inputDeviseAmount = item.children[2].lastElementChild;
        const againstValue = item.children[3].lastElementChild;

        selectDevise.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            getDeviseRateAjax(inputDevise, event.target.value, this.operationtypeValue);

            let $devise = $("#"+inputDevise.getAttribute('id')).val();
            let $deviseAmount = $("#"+inputDeviseAmount.getAttribute('id')).val();
            againstValue.value = calcAgainstValue($deviseAmount, $devise);
        });

        inputDeviseAmount.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            let $devise = $("#"+inputDevise.getAttribute('id')).val();
            let $deviseAmount = $("#"+inputDeviseAmount.getAttribute('id')).val();
            againstValue.value = calcAgainstValue($deviseAmount, $devise);
        });

    }

    removeItem(event) {

        const target = this.elementRowTarget;

        target.remove();

    }
}
```

I'd like my navbar not to shift upwards when I add a line to my html table.